# !seen query on Web IRC client (UnrealIRCd 5.0)

Tags: irc

I'm using a Web IRC client - UnrealIRCd 5.0 version.

In the main public channel, it has an option to type a query:

```
!seen [nickname]
```

which returns specific information about a certain nickname, and this info is visible in this main public channel to all other users.

However, I've noticed at least two users are using this !seen [nickname] query in a hidden mode that is not visible in a public channel.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! IRC commands sent as regular messages to a channel preceded by `!` are generally bot commands, meaning the command is handled by the bot and not the IRC server. We would need to know the bot software in order to appropriately answer this question. Some bots will support `!version` or `!help` to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to answer – it very much depends on the network/channel.

UnrealIRCd does not have any built-in "channel" commands. These are usually provided either by the main "services" package (the same one which provides NickServ etc.) or by a separate chat bot that's in the same channel.

So it could be that:

- They are sending the same !seen command to a bot via private message (`/msg`, `/query`). It is impossible for us to know what the bot's name is, if there's any at all.
- They are sending a similar command to the SeenServ service, e.g. `/msg SeenServ [nick]` or `/msg SeenServ seen [nick]`. This service would be available network-wide, not just in the main channel.
- They are sending a *different* command to the services, e.g. `/msg NickServ info [nick]` is common and often provides the same or at least similar information.